# How to add two dynamic footers in laravel dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel

I had added a dynamic footer text in ten pages single PDF file but now I am stuck in adding two different footers for different pages in the **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf** composer package in laravel.

I have to add two different footer texts for two different pages in a ten pages single pdf file generated by the above package.

For example:-

- Page_1 => footer_text_1 with page_number_1
- Page_2 => footer_text_1 with page_number_2
- Page_3 => footer_text_1 with page_number_3
- Page_4 => footer_text_2 with page_number_1 (again)
- Page_5 => footer_text_2 with page_number_2

Please help me out as it's my client's requirement.
Below I am sharing my pdf-generating code.

Here is my controller code:-

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView($viewPath, [
                    'pdf' => true,
                    'key1' => 'value1',
                    'key2' => 'value2'
                ])->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif', 'enable_php' => true])->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->save('' . $path . '/' . $fileName . '.pdf');
return $pdf->download($fileName . '.pdf');
```

Here is my blade file code for generating one footer text with dynamic page numbers for every single page:-

```
At the top of the body tag-

<footer>
    Footer text here
</footer>


At the bottom of the body tag-

<script type="text/php">
    if ( isset($pdf) ) {
        $font = null;
        $pdf->page_text(295, 810, "{PAGE_NUM}", $font, 10, array(0,0,0));
    }
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Thank you in advance!!